# Python manipulating json, lists, and dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, dictionary

Sorry for the length but tried to be complete.

I'm trying to get the following data - 
(only small sampling from a much larger json file, same structure)

```
{
    "count": 394,
    "status": "ok",
    "data": [
        {
            "md5": "cd042ba78d0810d86755136609793d6d",
            "threatscore": 90,
            "threatlevel": 0,
            "avdetect": 0,
            "vxfamily": "",
            "domains": [
                "dynamicflakesdemo.com",
                "www.bountifulbreast.co.uk"
            ],
            "hosts": [
                "66.33.214.180",
                "64.130.23.5",
            ],
            "environmentId": "1",
        },
        {
            "md5": "4f3a560c8deba19c5efd48e9b6826adb",
            "threatscore": 65,
            "threatlevel": 0,
            "avdetect": 0,
            "vxfamily": "",
             "domains": [
                "px.adhigh.net"
            ],
            "hosts": [
                "130.211.155.133",
                "65.52.108.163",
                "172.225.246.16"
            ],
            "environmentId": "1",
        }
    ]
}
```

if "threatscore" is over 70 I want to add it to this json structure - 
Ex. 
        "data": [
            {
                "md5": "cd042ba78d0810d86755136609793d6d",
                "threatscore": 90,

```
{
"Event":
    {"date":"2015-11-25",
    "threat_level_id":"1",
    "info":"HybridAnalysis",
    "analysis":"0",
    "distribution":"0",
    "orgc":"SOC", 
    "Attribute": [
        {"type":"ip-dst",
        "category":"Network activity",
        "to_ids":True,
        "distribution":"3",
        "value":"66.33.214.180"},
        {"type":"ip-dst",
        "category":"Network activity",
        "to_ids":True,
        "distribution":"3",
        "value":"64.130.23.5"}
        {"type":"domain",
        "category":"Network activity",
        "to_ids":True,
        "distribution":"3",
        "value":"dynamicflakesdemo.com"},
        {"type":"domain",
        "category":"Network activity",
        "to_ids":True,
        "distribution":"3",
        "value":"www.bountifulbreast.co.uk"}
        {"type":"md5",
        "category":"Payload delivery",
        "to_ids":True,
        "distribution":"3",
        "value":"cd042ba78d0810d86755136609793d6d"}]
}
}
```

This is my code -

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import json
from pprint import pprint

now = datetime.now()

testFile = open("feed.json")
feed = json.load(testFile)


for x in feed['data']:
    if x['threatscore'] > 90:
        data = {}
        data['Event']={}
        data['Event']["date"] = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        data['Event']["threat_level_id"] = "1"
        data['Event']["info"] = "HybridAnalysis"
        data['Event']["analysis"] = 0
        data['Event']["distribution"] = 3
        data['Event']["orgc"] = "Malware"
        data['Event']["Attribute"] = []
        if 'hosts' in x:
            data['Event']["Attribute"].append({'type': "ip-dst"})
            data['Event']["Attribute"][0]["category"] = "Network activity"
            data['Event']["Attribute"][0]["to-ids"] = True
            data['Event']["Attribute"][0]["distribution"] = "3"
            data["Event"]["Attribute"][0]["value"] =x['hosts'] 
        if 'md5' in x:
            data['Event']["Attribute"].append({'type': "md5"})
            data['Event']["Attribute"][1]["category"] = "Payload delivery"
            data['Event']["Attribute"][1]["to-ids"] = True
            data['Event']["Attribute"][1]["distribution"]  = "3"
            data['Event']["Attribute"][1]['value'] = x['md5']
        if 'domains' in x:
            data['Event']["Attribute"].append({'type': "domain"})
            data['Event']["Attribute"][2]["category"] = "Network activity"
            data['Event']["Attribute"][2]["to-ids"] = True
            data['Event']["Attribute"][2]["distribution"] = "3"
            data['Event']["Attribute"][2]["value"] = x['domains']
        attributes = data["Event"]["Attribute"]
        data["Event"]["Attribute"] = []
        for attribute in attributes:
            for value in attribute["value"]:
                    if value == " ":
                        pass
                    else:
                        new_attr = attribute.copy()
                        new_attr["value"] = value
                        data["Event"]["Attribute"].append(new_attr)
        pprint(data)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

And now it seems to be cleaned up a little but the data['md5'] is being split on each letter and I think it's just like L3viathan said earlier I keep overwriting the first element in the dictionary... but I'm not sure how to get it to keep appending???

```
{'Event': {'Attribute': [{'category': 'Network activity',
                          'distribution': '3',
                          'to-ids': True,
                          'type': 'ip-dst',
                          'value': u'216.115.96.174'},
                         {'category': 'Network activity',
                          'distribution': '3',
                          'to-ids': True,
                          'type': 'ip-dst',
                          'value': u'64.4.54.167'},
                         {'category': 'Network activity',
                          'distribution': '3',
                          'to-ids': True,
                          'type': 'ip-dst',
                          'value': u'63.250.200.37'},
                         {'category': 'Payload delivery',
                          'distribution': '3',
                          'to-ids': True,
                          'type': 'md5',
                          'value': u'7'},
                         {'category': 'Payload delivery',
                          'distribution': '3',
                          'to-ids': True,
                          'type': 'md5',
                          'value': u'1'},
```

And still getting the following error in the end:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hybridanalysis.py", line 34, in 
    data['Event']["Attribute"][1]["category"] = "Payload delivery"
IndexError: list index out of range

The final goal is to get it set so that I can post the events into MISP but they have to go one at a time.

Comment: Reconsidered, I think your actual problem is that you read something in data and then overwrite it every time `threatscore` is above 70.

Comment: Hey L3viathan! I think it's exactly like you're saying but how do I keep from overwriting it and just get it to append another 'event' as it continues through the for loop.

Comment: Change data to be a list, which you define outside your loop. In the loop, just append a new event dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should fix your problems. I added the attribute dictionary all in one go, and moved the data in a list (which is more appropriate), but you might want to remove the superfluous list which wraps the Events.

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import json
from pprint import pprint

now = datetime.now()

testFile = open("feed.json")
feed = json.load(testFile)

data_list = []

for x in feed['data']:
    if x['threatscore'] > 90:
        data = {}
        data['Event']={}
        data['Event']["date"] = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        data['Event']["threat_level_id"] = "1"
        data['Event']["info"] = "HybridAnalysis"
        data['Event']["analysis"] = 0
        data['Event']["distribution"] = 3
        data['Event']["orgc"] = "Malware"
        data['Event']["Attribute"] = []
        if 'hosts' in x:
            data['Event']["Attribute"].append({
                'type': 'ip-dst',
                'category': 'Network activity',
                'to-ids': True,
                'distribution': '3',
                'value': x['hosts']})
        if 'md5' in x:
            data['Event']["Attribute"].append({
                'type': 'md5',
                'category': 'Payload delivery',
                'to-ids': True,
                'distribution': '3',
                'value': x['md5']})
        if 'domains' in x:
            data['Event']["Attribute"].append({
                'type': 'domain',
                'category': 'Network activity',
                'to-ids': True,
                'distribution': '3',
                'value': x['domains']})
        attributes = data["Event"]["Attribute"]
        data["Event"]["Attribute"] = []
        for attribute in attributes:
            for value in attribute["value"]:
                    if value == " ":
                        pass
                    else:
                        new_attr = attribute.copy()
                        new_attr["value"] = value
                        data["Event"]["Attribute"].append(new_attr)
        data_list.append(data)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data_list, outfile)
```

Comment: L3viathan Grazi!!!!  You've got data ={} is the name of the 'scratch' dictionary which doesn't really matter because that name won't be in the final json structure.   Inside of data you create data['Event']={}  which is where you add the json back in and it's basically a dictionary so just type it out - data['Event']["info"] = "HybridAnalysis" which matches the structure needed to post. Attributes you .append because then it's a list and we are appending the dictionaries as part of the list.  I don't get why MD5 is still being split out into separate characters??

Comment: In other words why would it split the 'MD5' into individual characters and not do the exact same thing to the 'hosts' and 'domains'?  It splits those lists correctly on the commas.

Comment: @mathurin68 Ah, I see. Because it's iterating over that value. If you iterate over a list (like domains, or hosts), you get strings. If you iterate over strings, you get single-character strings.

Answer (score 1):

In the json, "Attiribute" Holds the value of a list with a 1 item, a dict, in it, as shown here.

```
{'Event': {'Attribute': [{'category': 'Network activity',
                      'distribution': '3',
                      'to-ids': True,
                      'type': 'ip-dst',
                      'value': [u'54.94.221.70']}]
...
```

When you call `data['Event']["Attribute"][1]["category"]` you are getting the second item (index 1) in the list of attribute, while it only has one item, which is why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks L3viathan!  Below is how I tweaked it to not iterate over MD5's.

```
    attributes = data["Event"]["Attribute"]
    data["Event"]["Attribute"] = []
    for attribute in attributes:
        if attribute['type'] == 'md5':
            new_attr = attribute.copy()                        
            new_attr["value"] = str(x['md5'])
            data["Event"]["Attribute"].append(new_attr)
        else:
            for value in attribute["value"]:
                new_attr = attribute.copy()                        
                new_attr["value"] = value
                data["Event"]["Attribute"].append(new_attr)
    data_list.append(data)
```

Manipulating json seems to be the way to go to learn lists and dictionaries.